# Sendgrid sent_at nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, email, sendgrid

the problem that I have is that I'm using https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs to send email through the API and everytime I use the sent_at function, my email has the type : "Drop" in my Sendgrid Dashboard and the reason is : "invalid SMTPAPI header". I really can't find why... Here's my code :

```
var email = new sendgrid.Email({
  to:       "test@myemail.com",
  from:     "me@noreply.com",
  subject:  "TEST"
});

var now = moment();
now.add(4, 'days');
email.setSendAt(now.unix());

sendgrid.send(email, function(err, json) {
  if (err) { return callback(err); }
  console.log("json email promo response ->", json);
  return res.status(200).end();
});
```

I'm trying to schedule my email to be sent 4 days later. When I execute this, I receive the "json email promo response -> success". So everthing seems to work well. But when I go in my dashboard with Sendgrid, it doesn't process my email.

Thank you very much!
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried to fix your header thanks to [smtp api header validator](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/smtpapi_validator.html) . It's a really helpful parser.

When I put this it says invalid JSON :

`{
  to:       "test@myemail.com",
  from:     "me@noreply.com",
  subject:  "TEST"
}`

But it's validated by the parser this way :

`{
    "to": [
        "test@myemail.com"
    ],
    "from": "me@noreply.com",
    "subject": "TEST"
}`

I had to create an array for `"to"`'s value, and I added double quotes around keys. 
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about the stmp api header validator, Great tool ! But my problem is in the sent_at. One person just told me that I can't schedule an email more than 24 hours with Sendgrid.. I don't know if it's true. Because my email works when I comment the line : "var now = moment();now.add(4, 'days');email.setSendAt(now.unix());"

Comment: Hmm, I do not see any limitations in time in this document : https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/scheduling_parameters.html

This setSendAt function must be correctly setting the send_at parameter ([https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/lib/email.js]), but just to be sure, set it by yourself, because you have an error from the header and `send_at` is a header parameter.
Instead of `email.setSendAt(now.unix());` try `email.send_at = now.unix()`

Comment: I tried your code with my credentials, and I had an error which said : `[Error: Missing email body]`, so do `email.text = 'This is my first email through SendGrid'` or set it at the beginning and then try again.

Comment: By this way, if sendGrid does not support 4 day scheduling, you might want to create yourself a task queue in which you pushes your emails with the sent_at params as key... and you execute every task when the unix timestamp is older than the current time.